# HTTP basic authentication using javascript best methods

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, http-authentication, basic-authentication

I have html5 + javascript +phone-gap app for ios.
I need to connect to a protected url and pass HTTP basic authentication in base64 to get a rss feed.  Am not using jquery in the app and look good advice and best practices to get this done.

Thank you